# Schwarzschild in 5d

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, mathematical-modeling, symmetry, general-relativity

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data
   The most general form:

$ds^2=e^{2A(r)}dt^2-e^{2B(r)}dr^2-r^2(d\theta_1^2 +sin^2\theta_1(d\theta^2_2+sin^2\theta_2d\phi^2))$

Ricci tensors:

$R_{tt}=e^{2(A-B)}(\frac{3A'}{r}+A'^2-B'A'+A'')$
$R_{rr}=-A''+\frac{3B'}{r}+A'(B'-A')$
$R_{\theta_1 \theta_1}=2+e^{-2B}(-2+r(B'-A'))$
$R_{\theta_2 \theta_2} = sin^2 \theta_1 R_{\theta_1 \theta_1}$
$R_{\phi \phi} = sin^2 \theta_1 sin^2 \theta_2 R_{\theta_1 \theta_1}$

To solve the Ricci tensors for $A$ and $B$?

2. Relevant equations
3. The attempt at a solution

I have tried preceeding as you do in the 4-d case. This is to do
$e^{-2(A-B)} R_{tt} + R_{rr} =0 $
which gives $A=-B$

and then to solve
$R_{\theta_1 \theta_1}=0$
and then $R_{rr}$

However doing this i get:

$1+e^{2A}(1-A') = 0$
multiply though by $e^{-3A}$
to get
$d/dr(e^{-A}r)=-e^{-A}$

$$e^{-A}r=\int -e^{-A} dr $$

and I can't  solve for $A(r)$ explicitly

I can't see a better way to proceed as with the other components there are terms including $A'' , A'^2$ things.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You somehow lost a factor $r$ in your equation.
If I repeat your calculation, I end up with
$$1-e^{2A}(1+r A')=0$$
which solves nicely to 
$$A(r)=-\frac{1}{2} \log\left(\frac{1}{\frac{k}{r^2}-1}\right)$$